# On Convergence of Alternating Harmonic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I am almost new with Mathematical Analysis and I see something that made me to think! It is proved that Alternating Harmonic Series is convergent to `ln(2)`. What if we remove some element from first of it. Does it remain convergent yet and does we could do normal algebraic operation to calculate its sum?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You mean like $\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\cdots=\ln(2)-1+\frac12$, e.g.?

Comment: Hint: as an instructive exercise, prove (using the definition) that for *any* series, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n=S$ then $\sum_{n=2}^\infty u_n=S-u_1.$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes I mean that exactly. You know that if we change order of that series then we may converge to different result. Although it seems non related, I try to to power that series up to two in order to calculate another series (1/n2 ) and Then I fall in that situation!

Comment: @AnneBauval Aha, Thank you. Yes according to that simple hint, I get my answer mathematically;)